# Reputation decrease

Tags: support, review-queues, answers, reputation, downvotes

I opened an answer for review and saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753303/4169008
I flagged "it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech" and voted down. Few minutes later I saw that my reputation was decreased (on 1 point) for this post. Why?

Really, it is not a problem for me, I'm not petty, just want to know did I something wrong or it is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for link. I had made two actions in a same time and didn't understand which of them cost reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You voted down an answer.

That costs you 1 reputation.

No bug here.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on Meta Stack Exchange.